# How to convert an absolute path to a relative one?

Tags: c++, filesystems

Let's say I have a base path `D:\files` and an absolute path `D:files\images\1.jpg`.
Is there a way to convert this absolute path into a relative one with respect to the base path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`std::filesystem::relative`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/relative) (C++17 needed)

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::filesystem::relative("D:files/images/1.jpg", "D:files") << "\n";
    std::cout << std::filesystem::relative("D:files\\images\\1.jpg", "D:files") << "\n";
}
```

Output

```
"images\\1.jpg"
"images\\1.jpg"
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Kv636rf4G)

Comment: IMHO, `D:files` is not an absolute path but a relative path on drive `D:`. AFAIR, the Windows has a current directory _per drive_. Nevertheless, I'm surprised that the `std::filesystem::relative()` worked in your sample for all that. Maybe, it's a mere string operation...